# Python Unicode - Can't print some unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode

I was trying to print random Unicode characters in Jupyter Notebook. In general, I am able to print characters but there are many which I can't print. Although I couldn't keep track of other examples, the following one is the I was able to reproduce -

```
str('\u1F600') #o/p is 'ὠ0' but actually it is a Grinning Face
```

I remember that in at least 2 other cases, the output was some character followed by 0.

I am using Python 3.9 on Windows 8. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\u` only accepts 4 digits, so your string literal is being parsed as two separate characters, `\u1f60` and `0`.

```
>>> print('\u1f60')
ὠ
>>> print('0')
0
```

For larger code points, you need to use `\U` (which requires 8 digits, including leading 0s).

```
>>> print('\U0001f600')
```

Comment: I actually tried using `\U` but it didn't occur to me to add leading 0s. I though Python will handle this itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print("\U0001f600")
```

Output:

The problem with your code is that when you use \u, python thinks you are using 4 digits, and thinks the the 0 at the end is part of the rest of the string, so use the \U with extra hexadecimal digits (0) as digits a placeholder

Comment: While this answer is correct, it's usually better to explain *why* this works when OPs code doesn't (especially when it's not obvious).

Comment: You need to explain the code. In stack overflow code only answers is breaking the guidelines